# HashMap to ByteArray. из Java в Python

Tags: java, python

У меня есть HashMap конвертированный в ByteArray на Java. Как мне ByteArray на питоне конвертировать в map на python и обратно?

Код конвертирования HashMap в ByteArray

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    // Create raw data.
    Map<Integer, String> data = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
    data.put(1, "hello");
    data.put(2, "world");
    System.out.println(data.toString());

    // Convert Map to byte array
    ByteArrayOutputStream byteOut = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(byteOut);
    out.writeObject(data);

    // Parse byte array to Map
    ByteArrayInputStream byteIn = new ByteArrayInputStream(byteOut.toByteArray());
    ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(byteIn);
    Map<Integer, String> data2 = (Map<Integer, String>) in.readObject();
    System.out.println(data2.toString());
}
```

Comment: Вы хотите конвертировать в map именно результат работы кода на Java?

Comment: Или вам просто нужен аналог на Python приведённого java-кода?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import pickle

data = {
    1: 'hello',
    2: 'world'
}

byte_out = pickle.dumps(data)

data2 = pickle.loads(byte_out)

print(data)
```

Документация по модулю [pickle](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html)

Comment: А как на java сгенерировать код, который `pickle` поймет? :)

Comment: @gil9red на сколько я понял вопрос, автор умеет делать сериализацию на Java, но не знает этого термина и не умеет делать её на Python, поэтому пример кода на Java был единственным для него способом объяснить, чего же он хочет увидеть на Python. А может я и ошибаюсь.

Answer (score 1):

Можно попробовать найти парсер для продуктов Java Serialization API [вроде этого](https://github.com/tcalmant/python-javaobj). Но это звучит как очень плохая идея.

Для обмена данными между разными языками программирования используйте платформо- и языконезависимые форматы сериализации: XML, JSON, Protobuf, Thrift и.т.п.